# Document viewer for ipad

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ms-office

I am new to Xcode world. I am working in Xcode to develop a Document Viewer for Ipad that support DOC and PPT file types. I googled it so many times, but nothing useful. I badly need a library. Please help me to choose a library for ios to support MS Documents and Powerpoint.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html

It works fine for excel, word, pdf, images,...But I didn't test it for PPT files.

Comment: If you found any answers right, then you have to accept the answer by clicking the "right" icon in near the answer. (and you can upvote the answer too)

Comment: thank you. It does what you said.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to view PDFs and PPT files (as well as Word documents) then you can simply use a `UIWebView`

Comment: ,sorry i tried it. PDF works fine but not DOC.

Comment: I've used UIWebView for displaying Word Documents. Are you sure the DOC version is 97 or later? See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1630/_index.html

Comment: doc and docx work great in UIWebView at least as of iOS 6, iOS 5 worked some of the time...