# How do I display iWork, Office, or other document types in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, iwork

I receiving the iWork files(Pages,Numbers and keynote), .pdf, .txt and rtf files URL from the server. I try to open the url in web view but not succeed. UIWebview display nothing when i load the url.here is my code

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url of which i'm reciving from the server"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

Is there any other way to open the following type of files in application?
Any help can be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The UIWebView is supposed to render websites, not documents (PDF might work).

You should take a look in this Apple Developer Example and an other StackOverflow post (this might be a duplicat):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DocInteraction/Introduction/Intro.html
[Document viewer for ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13399738/document-viewer-for-ipad)